# Creating a nested JSON object from SQL results

Tags: javascript, php, mysql, sql, json

I'm trying to figure out how to create a nested JSON object, something like this:

```
company: "Company 1",
pricing: {
    term: "1 year",
    price: "$4.95",

    term: "2 years",
    price: "3.95"
},
```

I have two tables in MySQL, one called plans which is structured in this fashion

```
| id |  company  |
------------------
|  2 | company 1 |
```

and another table plans_pricing to represent the pricing data

```
| id | plans_id |  term  | price | 
--------------------------------
| 1  |   2      | 1 year | $4.95 |
| 2  |   2      | 2 years| $3.95 |
```

I am using Laravel 4 to query the database and create json to send back to my ajax request. Here is the query, which is currently sending a server 500 error.

```
public function results()
{
    $answers = $_POST['answers'];

    $data = DB::table('plans')
                ->join('plans_pricing', 'plans.id', '=', 'plans_pricing.plans_id')
                ->select('plans.company', 'plans_pricing.price', 'plans_pricing.term')
                ->whereIn('plans.id', $answers)
                ->get();

    echo json_encode($data);
}
```

I'm not sure why this query isn't working, but that isn't even why i'm asking this question. I need to know how to get a nested JSON object, when I create the join, I believe that I'll receive a separate object for each, like here:

```
 |     company     |  price  |  term  |
  ------------------------------------
 |    company 1    |  4.95   | 1 year | 
 |    company 1    |  3.95   | 2 years|
```

How can I make this SQL query return a nested JSON object like the one I describe above? I have been stuck on this problem for two days now and could really use some guidance. Thanks

UPDATE:

The server 500 error was fixed by changing `echo json_encode` to `return Response::json($data);`

Comment: what is the value for $answers ?

Comment: typically an array of ids, such as 2, 3 , 4. But for this simplicity just assume `$answers = 2`, the `id` of `company1`

Comment: have you verified that your query is executing properly, like check to see if it errors out, or that `$data` actually contains rows

Comment: I don't receive any errors, aside from a server 500 error when I console.log the ajax request. The query was working great until I added the join

Comment: If you are using laravel instead of echo json_encode use return Response::json($data);  Also if you are in chrome open you developer tools go to network and select the ajax request when you make it, what error does it give?

Comment: aside from the error, I don't think the query above will even return a nested json object would it? How can I create a nested json object from a query?

Comment: You cannot create the object you wish to receive solely from a SQL query. You will need to iterate the resultset and create your own object.

Comment: @Ohgodwhy Okay that's what I'm wanting to know, where can I find out how to iterate the result set to create a nested object?

Comment: You would use `->each` on the collection object. A list of methods available on collections [is available here](http://laravel.com/api/class-Illuminate.Support.Collection.html)

Comment: @RickLancee after changing from `echo json_encode` to `return Response::json($data);` I am not having the server 500 error anymore. Thanks. Now I just need to figure out how I can create an nested JSON object from my results

Comment: @Ohgodwhy Oh ok, so I would want to create the JSON object with PHP and not with Javascript in the ajax success function? Things are starting to become clearer...I really appreciate your help.

Comment: @mario Always put the grunt load of calculation on the server where possible. You never know how slow the device is that someone is using on your site.

Comment: @RickLancee why did you remove your answer? :( I was in the middle of trying to implement it

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I've never used Laravel but I think this *should* work:

```
$output = array();
$currentCompany = "";

foreach ($data as $datum) {
  if ($datum->company != $currentCompany) {
    $output[] = array();

    // get a reference to the newly added array element
    end($output);
    $currentItem = & $output[key($output)];

    $currentCompany = $datum->company;
    $currentItem['company'] = $currentCompany;
    $currentItem['rates'] = array();
  }
  $currentItem['rates'][] = array("price" => $datum->price, "term" => $datum->term);
}
```

json_encoded result:

```
[{
    "company":"company 1",
    "rates":[{
      "price":4.95,"term":"1 year"
    },{
      "price":3.95,"term":"2 years"
    }]
}]
```

Comment: I thought that I considered myself decently fluent in PHP, but I'm confused about a few parts of your solution. Why do you declare the `$output[] = array();` inside of the `foreach` loop as well as outside? Why do you use `end($output)` and the line i'm most confused about is `$currentItem = & $output[key($output)];` what is this line doing? Thanks again for your answer, it works beautifully, i'm just confused about how it works

Comment: I declare the entire variable $output to be an array (line 1).  Inside the loop, if the company is a NEW company, I create a new element in $output and set that to be an empty array as well.  Then I create a reference to the new array element - that's what the two lines prefixed with "get a reference to the newly added array element" do.  There are other ways to achieve the same result without using a reference.

Comment: interesting, thanks for the explanation. I really appreciate it

Comment: @James Does this conditional statement: `if ($datum->company != $currentCompany)` mean the same $datum->company value won't appear again after the other values?

Comment: @JeaffreyGilbert Correct.  The idea was to create one array element per company, with other $data values added to the existing element (for any given company).  For this to work the input list ($data) has to be sorted by company so all records for the same company are together.